# How to add a method to a dynamically created html element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, oop

I want to call a javascript class method when selecting an option using `<select onchange>`.

I tried adding the method when I append the select element expecting it to run the method when I select an option.

Instead it runs the method once when I add the new elements and then it says

`<select onchange="undefined">`

when I inspect.

`$(container).append("<select onchange='"+ this.editField() +"' id='" + this.selectId + "'>`

My index.php

```php
<?php include 'includes/header.php' ?>
<form action="includes/generate_form.php" id="survey_form" class="survey" method="post">
    <h1>Nytt formulär</h1>
    <div id="form_container"></div>
    <div onclick="new CustomField()">+</div>
</form>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php' ?>
```

My custom.js file

```js
class CustomField {
    constructor() {
        this.labelId = crypto.randomUUID();
        this.inputId = crypto.randomUUID();
        this.selectId = crypto.randomUUID();
        var container = document.getElementById("form_container");
        $(container).append("<label contentEditable='true' id='" + this.labelId + "'>Label</label>");
        $(container).append("<input id='" + this.inputId + "'>");
        $(container).append("<select onchange='"+ this.editField() +"' id='" + this.selectId + "'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option></select>");
    }
    editField() {
        alert("hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: So select it by the id after you add it and use addEventListener.

Comment: `this.editField` returns undefined; seems right. You’re calling the method, did you mean to give it a function reference? In any case: you’re trying to build up the tag with a string; “this” won’t be what you think it is by the time the handler fires.

Comment: Use event handlers instead of onchange

Comment: The HTML you're appending needs to be ... well... *HTML*.   `+this.editField()+` is not a string - you *probably* wanted: `append("<select onchange='editField()' id=...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't do exactly what you're trying to do.

`"<select onchange='"+ this.editField() +"' id='"...` is trying to append the non-String return value of a function as if it were a String.

Unfortunately, there's no way (without a bunch of crazy regexes) to convert just the non-String return value of a function into a String. If you were to pass the function itself – i.e. `+ this.editField +` (no parentheses) – the interpreter will gladly convert it to a String, but it's going to look like this:

```
editField() {
  alert("hello")
}
```

Hence the need for regexes to remove all the stuff you don't want (`editField()`, `{`, `}`, etc.), which is very messy. And of course, that chunk of code as is will throw errors, as `editField()` is now outside of the context of `CustomField`, so it's just invalid code.

The only option that I see for you, outside of changing how you're approaching this problem, is to simply return a String from `editField()`:

```
editField() {
  return "alert(\"hello\")";
}
```